# Is this sentence naturally phrased?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I have a context where two police officers are out driving. Suddenly a man that is not a police officer's voice comes over the police radio and starts talking to them. They answer him:

***How the hell did you get on this line?***

Does this sound perfectly natural in the context? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A "line" normally refers to a *telephone line*. They are more likely to refer to a radio bandwidth reserved for police as a '*channel*' or a '*frequency*'.

Other than that, the grammar seems pretty natural in the context, presuming the setting is present-day. Modern police radio is multi-encrypted, but in the past it may have been easier for amateur radio operators to get access to emergency services frequencies, and the reaction from a police officer may have been more one of annoyance than surprise.